# Como usar Deep-linking no React Native?

Tags: react-native

Como passar uma URL nesse formato **https://www.google.co.uk/?code=3a549132-8966-4ae1-a951-7e873452df3c&state=febe0bc9-8b38-4a78-a122-7e36c398a14a** pelo navegador de maneira que abra o aplicativo e mostre os parâmetros **code** e **state**?

Fiz dessa forma mas ele não ta exibindo o **code** e **state**

**App.tsx**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import React from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Routes from './routes';

import Home from './pages/Home';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const prefix = {
    prefixes: ['https://google.co.uk'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Home: {
          screen: Home,
          path: '/:code/:state',
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={prefix}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="#DDD" />
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#DDD' }}>
        <Routes />
      </View>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Home/index.tsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Container } from './styles';

const Home: React.FC = ({ route }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // para testar
    console.log('ROUTE: ', route)
  }, [route]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Text>Pagina Home</Text>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.google.co.uk" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score -3):

*https://github.com/AnkitDroidGit/ReactNative-Deeplink*

Esse é um exemplo bem completo!

Mas ele trata de deeep-link
Não dynamics-links.

Entre os dois é pouca diferença.

Aqui segue como implementar o dynamics-links --> (*https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage*)

Lembrando se vc usar uma arquitetura do tipo **REDUX** vai ter muito trabalho pra funcionar corretamente... boa sorte!!

:)